# Joining multiple tables in asp.net mvc5 using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to join two models and then select values from the joined table. What I've implemented is by far this from my understanding and gathering informations from different solutions in SO. But in x I'm always getting the values from first context `context.EventSessionTeamModels` but nothing from the second one. But everything from the `Select` block is needed to be fetched from the second one `context.SessionModels`. Maybe I've joined them in a wrong way. I need to know what needs to be done. Let me know if any other portion of the code is need other than the below code.

```
IQueryable<SessionShortModel>  shortInfoSession = context.EventSessionTeamModels
 .Join(context.SessionModels, x => x.session_id, y => y.session_id, (x, y) => x)
 .Where(x => x.event_id == eid && x.bp_id == attendeeId && x.role_code == "ATD")
 .Select(x => new SessionShortModel {
     StartTime = x.start_date,
     EndTime = x.end_date,
     Day = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.start_date),
     Year = x.start_date.Year,
     Month = x.start_date.Month,
     Name = x.session_name
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

May be it solve your issue. You get data from first table as you are using "x". Changing variable to "Y" you will get data from second table.

```
var data =(from ep in context.EventSessionTeamModels
             join e in context.SessionModels on ep.session_id equals e.session_id
             where ep.event_id == eid && ep.bp_id == attendeeId && ep.role_code == "ATD"
             select new SessionShortModel{
                 StartTime = e.start_date,
                 EndTime = e.end_date,
                 Day = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(e.start_date),
                 Year = e.start_date.Year,
                 Month = e.start_date.Month,
                 Name = e.session_name
             });
```

Comment: Maybe... care to explain why this would help?

Answer (score 0):

In EF you must to relationship the entities,  EventSessionTeamModels needs has the propierty SessionModels

```
List<SessionShortModel>  shortInfoSession = context.EventSessionTeamModels
 .Include("SessionModels")
 .Where(x => x.SessionModels.event_id == eid && x.SessionModels.bp_id == attendeeId && x.SessionModels.role_code == "ATD")
 .Select(x => new SessionShortModel {
     StartTime = x.start_date,
     EndTime = x.end_date,
     Day = DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.start_date),
     Year = x.start_date.Year,
     Month = x.start_date.Month,
     Name = x.session_name
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: I agree that navigation properties are more appropriate than joins, but the `Include` doesn't have any effect here, because the query ends with a projection.

Comment: EventSessionTeamModels must has the propierty IEnumerabe<SessionModels> sessionsModels = get;set; and the relationship  in the mapping [info](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)